# How to update element.styles css

Tags: html, css

The below style is causing mis-alignment of div element :

[image]

I don't know where this style is being set, ive searched the code base
but this seems to be set by the browser ?

How can this style be removed, when I remove the 'left' style using Chrome I get correct alignment. Where is this style being set ?

Here is the div where the style is being set:

This is the code :

```
<div class="multipleColumns" >
```

But when I inspect  the element on Chrome this is the code :

```
<div class="multipleColumns" style="left: auto; display: none;"
```

So it seems the styles ' style="left: auto; display: none;' are being injected at runtime ?

Comment: Need more info.. Share your HTML...

Comment: The element.style is either applied through javascript or set inline.

Comment: @ATOzTOA please see question edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.style` indicates that there is an inline style on the element which is not being read from the stylesheet.

e.g.

**css**

```
span.mystyle{ color: blue; }
```

**html**

```
<span class="mystyle" style="color: red;">test</span>
```

This will result in **red** text rather than **blue**.

The **inline style** will override your **stylesheet** styling, so you need to identify where this is being added to the element and remove it.

**Update**

Based on your edited question. It would seem as though the inline style is being added via JavaScript. You will need to find out where this is.

Comment: Re-read what I have said. The inline style overrides the stylesheet style.

Answer (score 0):

I think the styles are set in the elements styleblock directly in the hmtl code. Maybe you can share a snippet?

Have you tried an other browser? Maybe try it in Firefox with firebug installed. It might be, althought I think it would be really weird, a cache problem maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It is the inline style that you apply to the element.

for example

`<asp:DropDownList style="background-color:blue;" ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">`

and i have CSS

```
 select 
    {
        border:0px;
        outline:0px;
    }
```

if you inspect the dropdown you'll see

```
element.style {
background-color: blue;
}
Matched CSS Rules
select {
border: 0px;
outline: 0px;
}
```

EDIT: In order to get rid of `left:auto;` you can add in your CSS for instance:

```
left:100px!important;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use inline css for this, because the priority of inline css is more then external css.

Answer (score 0):

The style is being set within a javascript file :

```
$('.multipleColumns').css('left', 'auto').hide();
```